# Insert current user ID into DB using ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, gridview, sqldatasource

I need to insert the currently logged in user's ID into an Oracle database table using ASP.NET 4.5. I am using Windows Authentication with a local AD server.

When the admin user clicks the Override button, their ID needs to be inserted into another table (along with two other values) so that we know *who* the person doing the override was. So does this mean I need to have some sort of `OnClick()` method on the Override button that runs the SqlDataSource's Insert Command? Or am I going to have to do this entirely programmatically (and not using the SqlDataSource Insert Command)?

Here is the GridView I have so far:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CellPadding="6" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="20"
                  DataKeyNames="PP_TRANS_REF_NUM" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnOverride" runat="server" Text="Override" CssClass="pure-button pure-button-active" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PP_TIMESTAMP" HeaderText="Timestamp" SortExpression="PP_TIMESTAMP" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PP_CARD_CODE" HeaderText="Card Code" SortExpression="PP_CARD_CODE" ReadOnly="True" />
    ... (Extra Gridview columns, shortened for brevity.
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CxString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CxStringProviderName %>"
                   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Z_PCARD_PRELOAD"
                   InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Z_PCARD_OVERRIDE (PO_TIMESTAMP, PO_TRANS_REF_NUM, PO_AUTH_USERID) VALUES (:PP_TIMESTAMP, :PP_TRANS_REF_NUM, )"
                   FilterExpression="PP_MSG_CODE LIKE '%Z%'" >
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="PP_TIMESTAMP" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="PP_TRANS_REF_NUM" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have so far should pretty much work for you.  I think all you need to do is add `CommandName="Insert"` to your Button control:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOverride" runat="server" Text="Override" 
    CssClass="pure-button pure-button-active" CommandName="Insert" />
```

That way, the attached SqlDataSource control knows to execute the "InsertCommand" that you have set up for it.